# Getting 403 Forbidden with webchat on microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I have followed Option #4 in here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/speech/samples/speech/index.html
and used my COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY. But I keep getting a 403 forbidden even though the code seems to be passing in the `Authorization` header in the request as expected by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol).

Here is the Request and Response I captured from Chrome Developer tools:

> ## Request
>
> **URL:** wss://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?format=simple&language=en-US&Authorization=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.kK1bx_kWllytyDvdqSZlb0_HUwaLX-V6OGJGeJ3fI2k&X-ConnectionId=9B408F2612DE4902A2D37EEACC8FB350
>
> **Request Method**:GET
>
> **Status Code**:403 Forbidden
>
> ## Response Headers
>
> **Content-Length**:0
>
> **Date**:Sun, 28 May 2017 15:10:31 GMT
>
> **Server**:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>
> **X-MSEdge-Ref**:Ref A: B1DBE1CCBEEA44A6B0213CB1CF8B8CA6 Ref B: DEN02EDGE0314 Ref C: Sun May 28 08:10:31 2017 PST
>
> ## Request Headers
>
> **Accept-Encoding**:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>
> **Accept-Language**:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> **Cache-Control**:no-cache
>
> **Connection**:Upgrade
>
> **Cookie**:_IFAV=A=422B5EB35D6227B47A899A55FFFFFFFF&COUNT=0&SEEALL=2&VRSN=2;
>   SRCHD=AF=NOFORM; SRCHUSR=DOB=20160521;
>   MSFPC=ID=a0c448564466a044a98c006abcccbaf0&CS=3&LV=201608&V=1;
>   _RwBf=s=10&o=0&A=422B5EB35D6227B47A899A55FFFFFFFF; MUID=2350DC04198E61F62654DA0E1D8E6287;
>   _U=1Y4QobYDPj3fzheUKiZ5uMdlvmGHvPLxng61hD9XLEWEhcPAfnXyj4UgFgyOMlw6jiTZJaP9wfqB4D6B2UYIV7_jbXnm5WTRM0ycCG-1F5YbfcPhiTR4SdgSkfPadkYRd;
>   WLID=qgIk0rgVNCI8HNV2Z4g8xFSkWTapYBjrDBYC04Zh/6JNzAhx2KtSiq+zTmKuyODQY3+IA3XDFhKybijk6ArfNlzdJ448JV1JBNO/mmbbcGQ=;
>   ANON=A=422B5EB35D6227B47A899A55FFFFFFFF&E=13d0&W=1;
>   NAP=V=1.9&E=1376&C=GKfvIsAF38G7JJpiBtQFE1j-85HTsObRYo50Mrr-fkR1HpimpRoSRA&W=1;
>   ULC=T=CCC1|4:3; SRCHHPGUSR=CW=1329&CH=716&DPR=2&UTC=-360
>
> **Host**:speech.platform.bing.com
>
> **Origin**:https://ignitiontestbotweb.azurewebsites.net
>
> **Pragma**:no-cache
>
> **Sec-WebSocket-Extensions**:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
>
> **Sec-WebSocket-Key**:+oV+WOyiaN3VFOIYmX1t3w==
>
> **Sec-WebSocket-Version**:13
>
> **Upgrade**:websocket
>
> **User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110
>   Safari/537.36

---

The bing Speech API seems to be randomly accepting the calls. One in 10 connection attempts get through with a 101 Switch Protocols status code. for the same request.

### Success

> **Request** URL:wss://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?format=detailed&language=en-US&Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=0825dc93563445aca227aa125404c299&X-ConnectionId=2679C505D3D742A5809D1F08A1934E08
>
> **Request Method**:GET
>
> **Status Code**:101 Switching Protocols

---

### Failure (for same request)

> **Request URL**: wss://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?format=simple&language=en-US&Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=0825dc93563445aca227aa125404c299&X-ConnectionId=2A47A79398D941ACB3F67A9580B908E3
>
> **Request Method**:GET
>
> **Status Code**:403 Forbidden

Comment: Does this demo work for you? You just need to paste your API key. https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript/blob/master/samples/browser/Sample.html

Comment: Ok yeah I get the same, but please don't put credentials API keys in here. Are you sure that your key corresponds to "Bing Speech API"? You can check in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Its not Bing Speech API..... its for Custom Speech API. But based on documentation it looks to be using the same API.

Comment: No, those are two different services, I don't think the keys are interchangeable

Comment: Trying to implement WebChat bot using this code https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/speech   which internally uses   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript/tree/master/src/common.browser.   Are you aware of a way to call the Custom Speech API from a WebChat instead of the regular Bing Speech API?  
You are correct... I looked at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/customspeech-how-to-topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-use-endpoint and in the NOTE box it says that WebSockets are not supported.

Comment: Ok so you got the wrong key. The sample you are trying to follow is using the Speech API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the key you are trying to use corresponds to [Custom Speech Service API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/), and the sample you are trying to run [needs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/speech/samples/speech/index.html#L88) a [Bing Speech API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/) key. Bing Speech is the service that offers Speech to Text capabilites.